# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSelected')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, bar-chart, vue-chartjs

I was trying to implement a simple bar chart using Vue and Chart.js. But when I try to run the project I get:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSelected')
at popup.js:7:13**

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk8VX.png)

App.vue:

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

HelloWorld.vue:

```
    <template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  mounted () {
    console.log('Component mounted');
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              y: {
                  beginAtZero: true
              }
          }
      }
    });
    myChart;
  
  } 
}
</script>
```

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

error in the console screen. I have researched it but I couldn't find the proper solution. Can you please help me?

Comment: You forgot to get canvas context `const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d")`

Comment: That is not the issue, you can pass the context, node (as he is doing), jquery instance or just string with id to work. But the error states it is in popup.js, but there are no references to that in the code

Comment: For more information you should post the error stack of the popup.js since this seems to be the issue and not something in your code. May I also suggest using the vue-chartjs which you might find easier since it combines chartjs and vue